# Altium designer polygons

Tags: ground, altium, polygon

I'm trying to make a small trimming in polygon pour in Altium Designer.
I upload a photo.

How can I cut these edges and make it more flat?
[image]

Comment: That is caused by the clearance of your polygon to pads and traces. A cutout could work, but it's really cumbersome. There's an option that says "remove necks when copper width less than", try increasing that. Else, increase a little bit the clearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Polygon Pour Cutout (Place -> Polygon Pour Cutout). Place small cutouts in the place where you want to stop filling the polygon (use it like a dam).

Comment: That's my first thought. Is there anything more automatic?

Comment: @MrBit, the "automatic solution" is either don't put a polygon there to begin with, or just don't worry about it. Those strange shapes might not look pretty, but they won't mess up your circuit's functionality unless you're doing something really esoteric.

Comment: The only more "automatic" way I can think of is to increase the clearance rules for polygons.

Comment: Some traces have impedance control and I'm worried about it

Comment: I put larger clearance rules for my polygons and impedance controlled traces. Typically 3-4 times the distance to the ground plane.

Comment: The impedance controlled traces should have a calculated clearance, so if you modify these shapes to *not* follow that, you'll actually cause more mismatch!  I would leave them for that reason alone.